# 20.04LTS Upgrade button not working for me after being offered today Oct. 8, 2020?

Tags: upgrade

20.04LTS Upgrade button not working for me after being offered today Oct. 8, 2020. Computer meets all requirements, is running fully updated 18.04LTS. Did  my other computer the other day and all went well. Is there a problem with today's update/upgrade?

Comment: Run the software updater, install any outstanding updates, restart and it should work.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

In the `terminal`, do...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

and install any updates it shows there. Then run `Software Updater` again. Then you should be able to update to 20.04.

Comment: The same issue happens to me, the update process (18.04 - > 20.04) got interrupted due to an error once, and now the update button does not work, even when I am caught up on all software updates.

Comment: @Zhubarb Please start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are more comfortable with the [graphical user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) than the terminal, then simply open the main menu and look for "Software Updater". Run it and install all updates that it suggests. Once the updates have been installed it should offer you the the upgrade. It might tell you to restart in which case do so, and then run the "Software Updater" again, install anything it suggests and afterwards it offer the upgrade. The bottom line is that it won't offer the upgrade if there are outstanding updates.